# VBO's are not created properly in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, lwjgl, vbo

I have a 2D game set up using Vertex Buffer Objects, and each 'item' in the game has its own buffer created in a for loop before the game launches. I find that the first two 'Coin' items (they vaguely look like coins...) are created successfully, displaying their textures without fail, but the other two are just blank cubes... This leads me to believe that I am binding the vertices properly because it is displaying a quad, but the texture is not being buffered properly.

Here is my generating code:

```
 public void generateWorldLegacy() {

    for(Item item : world.items) {

        item.load();
                    //This makes the item class load its image 

         for(int i = 0; i < item.textureId.length; i++) {

             item.vboBuffer[i] = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVertices * vertexSize);

             item.vboBuffer[i].rewind();

             item.vboBuffer[i].put(

                         new float[] {

                         - item.width/2, - item.height/2,
                         + item.width/2, - item.height/2,
                         + item.width/2, + item.height/2,
                         - item.width/2, + item.height/2

             });

             item.vboBuffer[i].flip();

                 //TODO I have to make these public, put all the floatbuffers into arrays so I can dispose of them when the process is terminated

                 item.textureBuffer[i] = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVertices * textureSize);

                 item.textureBuffer[i].rewind();

                 item.textureBuffer[i].put(new float[] {

                            0, 1,
                            1, 1,
                            1, 0, 
                            0, 0

                 });

                 item.textureBuffer[i].flip();

                 item.vboId[i] = glGenBuffers();
                 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, item.vboId[i]);
                 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, item.vboBuffer[i], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

                 item.textureId[i] = glGenBuffers();
                 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, item.textureId[i]);
                 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, item.textureBuffer[i],       GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

             System.out.println(item.textureId[i] + "\n");

         }

    }

}
```

Here is my rendering code (for the items):

```
    public void renderWorld() {

    glTranslatef(-player.position.x, -player.position.y, 0);

    for(Item i : world.items) {

        glTranslatef(i.position.x, i.position.y, 0);

        if(i.position.y - horizon < player.position.y) { 

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i.vboId[i.spritePointer]);

        // vertices
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, i.vboId[i.spritePointer]);
        //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        // texCoords
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, i.textureId[i.spritePointer]);
        //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glTexCoordPointer(textureSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        // unbind VBO

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, amountOfVertices);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        }

        glTranslatef(-i.position.x, -i.position.y, 0);

    }



}
```

If I need to post my item code and my 'player' rendering code, I will, but I do not think that is the cause of the problem.

Here is an image of my result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvqopq2tmtmf8xd/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-16%20at%209.16.40%20PM.png

Comment: I am not familiar with LWJGL, but shouldn't the glBufferData function have one more argument? `void glBufferData(GLenum  target,  GLsizeiptr  size,  const GLvoid *  data,  GLenum  usage);`

Comment: @2am: Java OpenGL bindings typically use `Buffer` objects to pass in data instead of the size/pointer combinations we're used from the C bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Your object ids are mixed up. Just look at these two lines of code:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i.vboId[i.spritePointer]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, i.vboId[i.spritePointer]);
```

You're using the same ids for binding textures and buffers.